# Trying to understand this MIPS function that branches if its input is negative

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm reading the following excerpt about assembly language code:

"Labels can be used in assembly in replace[sic] of calculating exact values for branch and jump instructions. The following is an example."

```
int isNeg(int a0) {
  if (a0 < 0) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

isNeg:
  slt  $t0 $a0 $0
  beq $t0 $0 isPos
  jr $ra
isPos:
  add $v0 $0 $0
  jr $ra
```

Here's how I'm interpreting this (please correct me on any wrong assumptions I've made):

```
isNeg:
  slt $t0 $a0 $0 // store ($a0 < 0) in $t0
  beq $t0 $0 isPos // if ($t0 == 0) branch by 0 bytes
  jr  $ra
isPos:
  add $v0 $0 $0 // store 0+0=0 in $v0
  jr  $ra
```

So if my assumptions here are correct, then if $a is negative, we do nothing, and if $a is positive, then we branch by 0, which is the equivalent of doing nothing. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: if ($t0 == 0) the code jumps to "isPos:" and does an add.

Comment: Why do you think that `beq $t0 $0 isPos` would branch by 0 bytes?

Comment: You left out the commas between operands.  What MIPS assembler will actually parse this?  I assume there must be some, because we see asm like this from time to time in SO questions.  But clang chokes on it.

Comment: Note that the opposite of negative is not positive, that would exclude zero. 
 The term you want is "non-negative".  And BTW, this is a terribly inefficient implementation of the function: `srl $v0, $a0, 31` / `jr $ra` returns the sign bit of the input; a decent optimizing compiler should compile it to that.

Comment: Where did you even find this asm or that ungrammatical quote?  It leaves `$v0` unmodified for non-negative inputs, so it doesn't even correctly implement the C function.  Another valid single-instruction implementation of the function would be `slt $v0, $a0, $zero`

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone shed some light on this?

If I understand correctly, this text is from a book. The example is to show the effect of some instructions, not to show "real" code that can really be found in a real program (for example on a WLAN router with a MIPS CPU).

The only thing the writer of the book wants to show is how labels work so he wrote a (stupid) examples containing some labels.

> if $a is negative, we do nothing

Correct (assuming `jr $ra` is **not** a [delayed branch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_slot) as found in real MIPS CPUs)

I assume that the writer of the book forgot the `addi $v0 $0 -1` instruction.

> ```
> beq $t0 $0 isPos
> ```
>
> if $a is positive, then we branch by 0

This would be correct if `beq` **was** a [delayed branch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_slot).

In this case, the CPU would first execute the instruction immediately after the `beq` or `jr` instruction before actually branching/jumping.

However, in this case a `jr` instruction immediately following a `beq` instruction would not be allowed on most real MIPS CPUs. Therefore I don't think that this is the case here.

If an emulator not emulating delay slots is used, the `beq` instruction will jump by 4 bytes (over the `jr` instruction).

If a real MIPS CPU and an assembler inserting `nop` (e.g. `add $0 $0 $0`) instructions after each jump/branch instruction (`.set reorder` option in GNU) are used, the `beq` instruction will jump by 8 bytes (over the `jr` instruction and the `nop` instruction that follows it). After that jump the `add $v0 $0 $0` instruction is executed.

Comment: The branch *encoding* would still use an offset of `+1` instruction (4 bytes), because the branch target is encoded relative to the start of the instruction after `beq`.  (i.e. relative to the start of the instruction in the branch-delay slot).  And yes, this is clearly not asm for a real MIPS with `.set noreorder`, because of having back-to-back branches.